# "foo && bar || baz" in bash behaving differently from "if foo; then bar; else baz"

Tags: bash, shell-script

I thought

```
[ 1 -eq $1 ] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

Acts like

```
if [ 1 -eq $1 ]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

But, when I run this script (`nocmd` is a non-existing command)

```
#!/bin/bash

[ 1 -eq $1 ] && nocmd "yes" || echo "no"
```

I get a strange output for parameter '1':

```
me@ubuntu:/tmp$ ./ddd.sh 0
no
me@ubuntu:/tmp$ ./ddd.sh 1
./sh.sh: line 3: nocmd: command not found
no
```

Looks like it acts like:

```
if [ 1 -eq $1 ]; then
    nocmd "yes"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "no"
    fi
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Is it fine? Am I missing something?

Comment: It's no strange thing there, when you ran with `./ddd.sh 0` this part will check `[ 1 -eq $1 ]` it's not true (false) (1!=0), so this part won't run `&& nocmd "yes"` and this part will run  `|| echo "no"`, but when it's true `1=1` it will execute `&& nocmd "yes" ` part and since _shell_ doesn't recognize `nocmd` command, it's reported error `.... command not found` and again second part will run `|| echo "no"`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Except for the overall exit status, it acts like:

```
if
  ! { 
    [ 1 -eq $1 ] && nocmd "yes"
  }
then
  echo no
fi
```

In:

```
A || B
```

`B` is executed iff `A` fails. That's a OR operator.

In your case `A` is `[ 1 -eq $1 ] && nocmd "yes"` where `nocmd` is run iff `[` succeeds (a AND operator), in which case the exit status of `A` will be that of `nocmd`. In other words `echo no` will be executed if either `[` or `nocmd "yes"` fails (bearing in mind that `nocmd` is only run if `[` succeeds).

Those `x && y || z` are dirty hacks. They are best avoided for that very reason. Use a `if`/`then`/`else` construct if you do want a if/then/else logic. Use `x && y || z` only if you want `z` to be unless both `x` and `y` succeeded.

Even in:

```
cmd && echo OK || echo >&2 KO
```

The `echo OK` could fail under some pathological conditions (like stdout going to a file on a full filesystem), and `echo >&2 KO` could end up being executed as well.

```
$ bash -c 'true && echo OK || echo KO >&2' > /dev/full
bash: line 0: echo: write error: No space left on device
KO
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, what actually happens is this (and this is how `&&` and `||` works)

```
test 1 -eq $1
ret=$?
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
    nocmd "yes"
    ret=$?
fi
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "no"
fi
```

In your case, if `$1` does not equal `1`, **or is not a valid number**, then you have a non-zero `$?`, and the first `if` is skipped, and the second `if` prints "no". If `$1` equals `1` , then `nocmd "yes"` is executed, returning a non-zero `$?`, and "no" is also echoed.

Comment: That's not exactly true, and the reason is a bit weird. An if statement returns `0` if it doesn't run either of the `then` and `else` branches. So if the first test fails, `$?` is zero on the second test, always. `if false ; then echo x; fi; echo $?` prints `0`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Noted. I didn't know that before.

Comment: It's really more like that, at least I get the same result for that construct and the `&& .. ||` chain

Comment: @ilkkachu So you mean that my original version of code is **valid** but for more complicated reasons?

Comment: no, with the test directly against `$?`, the double-if gives a different result from the `&& ||`, since the first if-statement throws the second off. With the temporary variable the behavior matches. See: https://pastebin.com/q0Ct0Zw8 for the difference without the temp

Answer (score 3):

What you're missing is that `&&` and `||` operate on exit status of commands to the left of them - left associativity. You have here `some group of commands || echo "no"`, and `no` will be echoed if and only if  that group of commands returns non-success exit status.

What is that group of commands ? In first case you have `[ 1 -eq "$1" ] && echo "yes"`. If `[` portion failed, that'd be counted as fail exit status for `[ 1 -eq "$1" ] && echo "yes"`, therefore you'd `echo "no"` would run. Also  because of left associativity, when "$1" is 1, the  `[ 1 -eq $1 ]` returns success, then lets `nocmd` run which doesn't exist and shell will return error exit status, the whole group will have exit status of fail, hence `"no" is echoed.

By contrast, in your if statement

```
if [ 1 -eq $1 ]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

which route to take depends only on exit status of `[` portion. In `[ 1 -eq "$1" ] && echo "Yes" || echo "no"` echo also plays role as to whether or not `echo "no"` runs.

Your second if statement example is also different

```
if [ 1 -eq $1 ]; then
    nocmd "yes"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "no"
    fi
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

The `echo "no"` after `else`  doesn't depend on what happens to `nocmd` as in the chaining of logical operators.  Sure you still do the `echo "no"` part after doing `nocmd`, but here its exit status isn't grouped together with the whole `if` portion to which it belongs.